# Can't send large data from Android through TCP socket

Tags: c#, android, .net, sockets, xamarin

I'm trying to send an array of bytes from android (client) to Linux (server), I can send around 17kB but then the socket send an client socket timeout exception. At the server side I'm using netcat with the next command:

```
nc -l -p 55000 > out.txt
```

This works ok because I'm capable of sending files from other computer, for this reason I think the problem is at the client side (Android).

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin to compile the project and I tried many methods to send thought socket with the same result, between 15~20kB sended. Of course the permissions on Android to send through internet and other rights are ok.

This is the first mode I tried:

```
byte[] data = new byte[200000];
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.245", 55000);
client.SendBufferSize = 8192;
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
ns.ReadTimeout = 1000;
ns.WriteTimeout = 1000;
ns.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
ns.Flush();
ns.Close();
client.Close();
```

With this method only **around 17kB are received and the socket is not closed**, but the close methods are executed (I tested it with the debugger placing MessageBox to test in release).

Other method I've tested is this:

```
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.245"), 55000);
System.Net.Sockets.Socket sender = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

sender.ExclusiveAddressUse = true;
sender.LingerState = new LingerOption(true, 1);
sender.NoDelay = true;
sender.SendBufferSize = 8192;
sender.ReceiveBufferSize = 8192;
sender.SendTimeout = 1000;
sender.ReceiveTimeout = 1000;
sender.Ttl = 42;

try{
byte[] data = new byte[200000];
    sender.Connect(remoteEP);
    for (int a = 0; a < data.Length;)
    {
        int len = (data.Length - a) > 8192 ? 8192 : data.Length - a;
        a += sender.Send(data, a, len, SocketFlags.None);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     string a = e.ToString();
}
```

**The program send the first 8192 bytes and in the second round an socket timeout exception is trowed**. If I try to send all the bytes is one time the program executes the send method the returned bytes are the total length of the array, this mean all bytes are sent to the socket but only received 17kB.

I've tested other methods to do the same thing with the same results in two phones. The android version for compiler I'm using is 4.2. For VS and Xamarin the latest.

Also I tried to download an app from the market to send files throught TCP to see if the problem is in Netcat, firewalls, SO or other and the files was sended ok.... I'm very frustated, I think I'm doing well all the things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, in the loop of the second method I've changed the code when copying to stackoverflow to get it clear and done a mistake, the right loop is **without the a+=8192 in the for loop**

Comment: can't... don't see the option to edit

Comment: `sender.Send()`. Can it return 0? Or -1? When -1 possible then you should not just add -1 to your variable a. You better break from the loop then. Maybe also if 0 is returned. Better change to `int nsent = sender.Send()`. And check `nsent` for 0 or -1.

Comment: hi, yes, the code was like this but the problem is that sender.Send() trows and exception timeout in the second round,